# Git LFS , is it advisable to enable Git LFS in Bitbucket DataCenter Version

Tags: git, github, bitbucket-server

I am using Atlassian  Bitbucket Server , please share your thought / Guide on how you are using Git LFS in production environment.

We have integration with SAML for authentication.

Has any one using GitHub LFS features. How is it in terms of Performance.
Will git breaks incase developer pushes large files?

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I work for Atlassian on our Premier Support team.

LFS tracked files are pushed over HTTP and stored in your shared home directory (i.e. your shared NFS storage). By design, that LFS push is happening away from internal git processes. From an architectural point of view you're just pushing a lot of binary data over an HTTP connection, which is being written to disk on the other end. Performance is bounded by your reverse proxy (which can probably handle mostly anything you throw at it), the Apache Tomcat webserver that Bitbucket runs (which can also handle most anything you throw at it), and the performance of your shared NFS server. Git processes aren't used to handle the data stream, which keeps processing overhead low.

Lastly, for whatever it's worth, I've never seen an LFS performance issue that wasn't the result of an external environmental factor (e.g. client side bandwidth limitations). You should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Nice to meet you PS team member:)

Here is the concern:

Due to SAML integration at apache layer (with Shibboleth) the LFS web Trafic also redirects for SAML Sso auth. 
Since we use  open source SAML auth, which URLs needs to be filterd in Apache config.
 Do you know the LFS URL which needs to be bypass from SAML auth.?

Comment: @user4 Nice to meet you too! There are two URL patterns you should bypass so LFS requests go straight to Bitbucket, and not via your SAML provider: `/rest/git-lfs/storage` and `/scm/<project>/<repo>.git/info/lfs/objects/batch` (where <project> and <repo> are project keys and repo slugs, respectively.)

Comment: Yes, it working. Concern was since we use open source apache and shibboleth, what to do if this url changes in future :). , hope Atlassian keep this in there future changes

Comment: Thank a lot daveruinseverything